# “invalid option” error when running cucumber with “--retry”

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

This is a line from my cucumber.yml file in RubyMine

```
default: RDEE_BROWSER=chrome --no-source --color --format pretty --format html --out testresults/reportch.html --tags @current_tests
```

This works fine but when I add --retry 2 thus

```
default: RDEE_BROWSER=chrome --no-source --color --format pretty --format html --out testresults/reportch.html --retry 2 --tags @current_tests
```

I now get error as follows

```
invalid option: --retry (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

I am using cucumber 3.1.2 and ruby 2.6.5

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Please explain the context under which you receive the given error message. What do you do that triggers this error? Are you running a command? Are you doing something in RubyMine?

Comment: does this error occur if you run cucumber directly from the command line?

Comment: Hi @diabolist, interesting this works on the command line - cucumber --no-source --color --format pretty --format html --out testresults/reportch.html --retry 2 --tags.

Comment: So to comfirm from the command line as above all works well. When I put the same line in the cucumber.yml file in rubymine I still get the **error - invalid option: --retry (OptionParser::InvalidOption)**

Comment: You probably need to paste your full cucumber.yml in the question. Also cucumber.yml has nothing to do with RubyMine, its part of Cucumber. What we are trying to find out here is how you are invoking Cucumber. I suspect you are doing this via RubyMine. If so the problem could be (a) bad cucumber.yml, (b) bad RubyMine

Comment: The `--retry` option was added in v3.0.0. Is it possible that you are some how pulling in an older version of Cucumber? For example, check what versions of Cucumber you have installed and your Gemfile (if you have one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the tip, you all helped me figure it out.
The problem was in my gemfile, it was locked to an older version of cucumber (2.2.0) even though command line cucumber --version returned 3.1.2

Now it is gem 'cucumber', '3.1.2' and after a nice bundle install retry is working

Thanks again